# How to use uuid:randomUUID() in policy builder @Novell

Tags: java, uuid, novell, novell-idm, netiq

I want to use predefined method of java using
`java.util.UUID:randomUUID()` for
`046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91` in place of CN,
but when i use this code in my policy, then it gives me
`com\.novell\.xsl\.extensions\.JavaObject@4c7261af` in place of CN.

So how can i solve this issue?

Here is my Policy :

```
<do-set-local-variable name="id1">
    <arg-string>
        <token-xpath expression="java.util.UUID:randomUUID()"/>
    </arg-string>
</do-set-local-variable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using String.valueOf(id) in place of CN, where id is the random UUID generated.

Regards

Comment: Try using the below, the idea is to use an "arg-string" instead of "arg-object"                                                                                <do-set-local-variable name="id1">
    <arg-string>
        <token-xpath expression="java.util.UUID:randomUUID()"/>
    </arg-string>
</do-set-local-variable>

Comment: i already used the <arg-string> in place of <arg-object> but no change in my cn

Comment: This should be working as per the documentation : http://www.novell.com/documentation/idm35/policy_dtd/data/dtddirxmldosetlocalvariable.html

Comment: how can i use "String.valueOf(id)" in my policy, can i need to import some other java class for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the xpath string() function to convert the UUID object into a string:

```
<policy xmlns:juuid="http://www.novell.com/nxsl/java/java.util.UUID">
    <rule>
    <description>set lv</description>
    <conditions>
        <and/>
    </conditions>
    <actions>
        <do-set-local-variable name="uuid" scope="policy">
            <arg-string>
                <token-xpath expression="string(juuid:randomUUID())"/>
            </arg-string>
        </do-set-local-variable>
    </actions>
</rule>
</policy>
```